# Xcode Signing error - The operation couldn’t be completed. (OSStatus error -2147416032.)

Tags: ios, xcode, flutter, apple-developer

I made a flutter app. Opened the `Runner.xcodeproj` and under

> runner>target>general>signing

When I select my AppleId for Signing it shows the following error:

> The operation couldn’t be completed. (OSStatus error -2147416032.).

I don't know how to resolve this please help.

I'm using `Xcode 10.2.1.`

Comment: Can you provide more details? Whether Signing is `Automatic` or `Manually` selected and others details

Comment: @Aditya It is selected as **Automatic**